# Laravel SEO Google json data with refering to mysql db

Tags: json, laravel, json-ld

I'm trying to improve our SEO in our Laravel project where we get the data for url for example from the db named as "slug".

The problem ill have currently is that this code for example isn't working:

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
    {
        "@context":"http://schema.org",
        "@type":"Restaurant",
        "url":"https://test.com/"{{$restaurant['slug']}},
        "priceRange":"$$",
        "@id":"https://test.com/"{{$restaurant['slug']}},
        "name":{{$restaurant['name']}},
        "address": {
            "@type":"PostalAddress",
            "streetAddress":{{$restaurant['address']}},
            "addressLocality":{{$restaurant['city']}},
            "addressRegion":{{$restaurant['city']}},
            "postalCode":{{$restaurant['zip']}},
            "addressCountry":"Switzerland"
            }
    }
</script>
```

The error ill get is as follow:
"Undefined variable: restaurant"

Can someone help out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to enclose in double quotes like so:

`"{{$restaurant['address']}}"`

Comment: thank you very much, was easier then ill thought. :)